# How to execute *.bat file fromHTML & Javascript from locally

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, local, execute

I want to execute sample.bat file locally from HTML/ Javascript

sample.bat:

```
start /d "\\server\Software\" sample.exe
```

In IE it working using **ActiveXObject** but it shows a popup like **run/Discard**

I don't want to come any popup when i lick on a button the bat file should run and execute the specified file

Comment: by webserver only )

Comment: I suppose you mean HTML in a browser and not Node.js or other similar engines. And I understand you already know how to do it, but you want to skip the user consent. Am I correct so far? If so, you might get better answers if you explain your context and your ultimate goal (rather than just the solution you've figured out).

Comment: Maybe you can find plugins that allow a JS to run a command, but that would be damn dangerous.

Comment: @Xenos that is not possible. Javascript cannot execute commands outside of the browser.

Comment: @RobLang "*plugins* that allow" As long as a plugin is involved, you can do anything (as long as it is allowed by browser's plugin policy). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527128/how-to-execute-an-external-application-using-firefox-addon#11535225

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run a `.bat` file from within the sandbox of the browser. *ActiveXObjects* will run in IE only and are regarded as a huge security hazard.

It is also not possible to run any command line from within a webpage. I would always suggest against this as a tactic.

Perhaps you might get a better answer if you explain what it is you're trying to achieve rather than the solution.

Comment: Thank for the response Rob, Actually I tried ActiveXObject in IE only.
I will explain what I was trying for, 
I have a .bat file inside the file I wrote "start /d "\\server\Software\" putty.exe" to install/run putty.
I just want to execute this from client side. is it possible Rob ?

Comment: Rob, Please share your thoughts